# Overwrite a Json Property in C# - Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I'm making a small JSON Parser.

This is the JSON I want to parse:

```
{"158023":{"prices":{"xbox":{"LCPrice":"225,000","LCPrice2":"232,000","LCPrice3":"235,000","LCPrice4":"235,000","LCPrice5":"239,000","updated":"15 secs ago","MinPrice":"27,000","MaxPrice":"500,000","PRP":"41"},"ps":{"LCPrice":"228,000","LCPrice2":"231,000","LCPrice3":"232,000","LCPrice4":"233,000","LCPrice5":"235,000","updated":"9 mins ago","MinPrice":"30,000","MaxPrice":"550,000","PRP":"38"},"pc":{"LCPrice":"305,000","LCPrice2":"305,000","LCPrice3":"315,000","LCPrice4":"333,000","LCPrice5":"347,000","updated":"1 hour ago","MinPrice":"37,000","MaxPrice":"700,000","PRP":"40"}}}}
```

And I have the following class, to represent the Json Object.

```
public partial class Prices
{
    [JsonProperty("158023")]
    public Token TokenNumber { get; set; }
}

public partial class Token
{
    [JsonProperty("prices")]
    public PricesClass Prices { get; set; }
}

public partial class PricesClass
{
    [JsonProperty("xbox")]
    public Pc Xbox { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ps")]
    public Pc Ps { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pc")]
    public Pc Pc { get; set; }
}

public partial class Pc
{
    [JsonProperty("LCPrice")]
    public string LcPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LCPrice2")]
    public string LcPrice2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LCPrice3")]
    public string LcPrice3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LCPrice4")]
    public string LcPrice4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LCPrice5")]
    public string LcPrice5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated")]
    public string Updated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MinPrice")]
    public string MinPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MaxPrice")]
    public string MaxPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PRP")]
    public string Prp { get; set; }
}

public partial class Prices
{
    public static Prices FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prices>(json, PriceConverter.Settings);
}

internal static class PriceConverter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}
```

I'm easily able to parse the JSON, by doing:

```
 Prices prices = Prices.FromJson(myJson);
```

The problem is when I want to use a different number than 158023.
For example, 158025.

The JsonProperty on the Prices class is already set to "158023", and I have no clue how to rename it.

TLDR:
I have a JSON Object, which I want to rename the JsonProperty text, before deserializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't know the key, use a `Dictionary<string, Token>` instead of the property `TokenNumber` in class `Prices`.

```
public partial class Prices
{
    // Remove this property
    // [JsonProperty("158023")]
    // public Token TokenNumber { get; set; }
}

public partial class Prices
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Token> FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Token>>(json, PriceConverter.Settings);
}
```

Now the result will be a dictionary where the key is the token value as an string and the value is a `Token` object.

Comment: Thanks alot. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `JsonExtensionData` and `OnDeserialized` attributes:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // Get the first key. If you have more than one, you may need
        // to customize this for your use case
        var id = _additionalData.Keys.FirstOrDefault();
        if (id != null)
        {
            // Assign to our Id property
            this.Id = id;

            // Create a reader for the subobject
            var itemReader = _additionalData[id].CreateReader();
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            // Deserialize the subobject into our Item property
            this.Item = serializer.Deserialize<Item>(itemReader);
            itemReader.Close();
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can try it [here](http://rextester.com/XLEI41941). Alternatively you could write a `JsonConverter` to achieve the same thing, or do what Amir suggested.

Comment: Thanks for this, but im going to use Amir's suggestion, since I was able to understand it a bit better